# What does '$?' command do/mean in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I came to know that using '$?' in powershell tells the user whether the previous command was successful in its execution or not by printing 'True' or 'False'.

Request for help/clarification on the following questions please:

First, I want to confirm whether what I stated in the first paragraph is true.

Secondly, if it is possible, a formal documentation on this command would be much welcome.

Thirdly, if what I have stated wrongly on the utility of the '$?' command in powershell, then I would like to know what its actual utility is.

Comment: see [get-help about_automatic_variable](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes, it's true.
2. @Kayasax has provided you an official doc from technet.microsoft.com

Try it on your own:
[image]

[Example (credits to yonglianglee)](http://www.cnblogs.com/yonglianglee/archive/2012/10/26/2741402.html):

> ? (dollar sign + question mark)  Returns True or False value
>   indicating whether previous command ended with an error. For some
>   reason it does not catch all errors, but most of the time it works.
>
> Task 1: See if a powershell cmdlet exists in the system. Code.

```
SomeCmdLet #does not exists
$?
$?
```

Output

```
The term 'SomeCmdLet' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the
spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:15
+ SomeCmdLet <<<<  #does not exists
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (SomeCmdLet:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
False    #error occured - previous cmdlet (SomeCmdLet) was not found
True     #no errors returned by the previous command ($?)
```

> Task 2: See if a WMI class exists in the system

```
gwmi win32_processo -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue   #intentional error, win32_processor is the right one
$?
$?
```

Output:

```
False
True
```